# How to stop page load code on add webpart to page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

When i am adding web part to page its page load call, Now problem is that it require some info on page load and it breaks. i do not want to execute my webpart page load code when i add it into a page. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Check the mode of the page in PageLoad method and perform the action depending on that. Example:
In case of web part page

```
if (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit)
    {
        ltr.Text = "EditMode2";
    }
    else
    {
        ltr.Text = "ViewMode";
    }
```

If it is a publishing page:

```
if (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Display)
  {
   // your code to support display mode
  }
  else // Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode = SPControlMode.Edit
  {
   // your code to support edit mode
  }
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478913/determine-display-mode-of-sharepoint-page